# Position icons in the form of arc using CSS

Tags: html, css

How can i position  tags in the form of arc and they are clickable links.[image]

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:3cm">
        <input type="image" src="icons\drawable-mdpi\ic_bb_logo.png" name="saveForm" class="btTxt submit" id="saveForm"/>
        <br>
        <div class="display_icons" style="display:none">
            <img src="icons\drawable-mdpi\ic_accesspoint.png" onclick="return ssid()"> 
            <img src="icons\drawable-mdpi\ic_profiles.png" onclick="return profile()">
            <img src="icons\drawable-mdpi\ic_water_consumption.png" onclick="return watercon()"> 
            <img src="icons\drawable-mdpi\ic_power_consumption.png" onclick="return powercon()">
            <img src="icons\drawable-mdpi\ic_logout.png" onclick="return logout()">
        </div>

    </div>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#saveForm").click(function(){
                $(".display_icons").toggle();
            });
        });
</script>
```

I need the arc as above image.Can any one help me how to do this??
Thankyou.

Comment: Have you tried something with CSS already, if so, can you share this as well?

Comment: Look into making an SVG element and adding the logo's based on Polar coordinates. Or just make all of your logo's an absolute position and still use Polar coordinates

Comment: I dint applied any CSS upto now i dont have idea how to do it.So,Can u please help me@Roberrrt

Comment: can you provide any samle code how to do it@broodjetom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.circle-container a {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%; 
 width: 4em; height: 4em;
 margin: -2em; 
    border-radius: 50px;
}
circle-container img { display: block; width: 100%; }
.deg0 { transform: rotate(-25deg) translate(15em); } 
.deg45 { transform: rotate(-5deg) translateX(18em); }
.deg30 { transform: rotate(10deg) translate(21em) rotate(-315deg);}
.deg315 { transform: rotate(315deg) translate(12em) rotate(-315deg);}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- content to be placed inside <body>…</body> -->
<div class='circle-container'>
 <a href='#' class='deg0'><img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-1994-02-c-thumb.jpg'></a>
 <a href='#' class='deg45'><img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2005-37-a-thumb.jpg'></a>
 <a href='#' class='deg315'><img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2004-32-d-thumb.jpg'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg30'><img src='http://imgsrc.hubblesite.org/hu/db/images/hs-2004-32-d-thumb.jpg'></a>
</div>

<script>
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: this is circle i need in the form of arc

Comment: You can change css value to get what you need.